# How do I get KivyMD Navigation Drawer to call another app in a separate .py file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I know how to write an app with kivy and I understand how to make a KivyMD app that has a navigation drawer. I can make the apps run individually but how do I combine the two?

I am new to coding and I am stuck here. Below are the codes for two mock-up apps for training purposes only. The first is a very simple app called "+5 Game" that allows the user to click a button to add 5 to the total which is then displayed in the GUI.

The second is a KivyMD app with a navigation drawer that contains two buttons. One to go to the home screen and one to go to the "+5 Game"

How do I link the button in the navigation draw to the +5 game?
And what do I do about the imports at the top of the file?

This is the code for the +5 Game:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton


class ClickToAdd(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        self.num = 0

        self.display_number = MDLabel(text="0", font_style="H1", halign="center",
                                      pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8})
        self.add5_BTN = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="+5", pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.65},
                                              on_release=self.add5_CMD)

        self.screen.add_widget(self.display_number)
        self.screen.add_widget(self.add5_BTN)

        return self.screen

    def add5_CMD(self, *args):
        self.num = self.num + 5
        self.display_number.text = str(self.num)


ClickToAdd().run()
```

This is the main GUI of the KivyMD app with a navigation drawer and a screen manager:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Home"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "home"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Play +5 Game"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "plus5game"


Screen:
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "Navigation Drawer Test"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: "home"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Home Screen Stuff Goes Here"
                    halign: "center"

            Screen:
                name: "plus5game"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "+5 Game Goes here"
                    halign: "center"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run one `App` inside another `App`, but you can use the guts of another `App` inside the first. In your case, you can redefine the the `Plus5` `App` like this:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton

class Plus5Screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Plus5Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num = 0

        self.display_number = MDLabel(text="0", font_style="H1", halign="center",
                                      pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8})
        self.add5_BTN = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="+5", pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.65},
                                              on_release=self.add5_CMD)

        self.add_widget(self.display_number)
        self.add_widget(self.add5_BTN)

    def add5_CMD(self, *args):
        self.num = self.num + 5
        self.display_number.text = str(self.num)


class ClickToAdd(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Plus5Screen()
        return self.screen

if __name__=='__main__':
    ClickToAdd().run()
```

and save this is a file named `plus5.py`.

Then in you main `App`, you can just reference this in the 'kv':

```
KV = '''
#:import Plus5Screen plus5   # import the guts of the Plus5 game
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Home"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "home"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Play +5 Game"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "plus5game"


Screen:
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "Navigation Drawer Test"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: "home"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Home Screen Stuff Goes Here"
                    halign: "center"

            Plus5Screen:  # this creates the guts of the Plu5 game
                name: "plus5game"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''
```

Comment: Brilliant. Another question. If I want to add another game (for example "Plus 6") to another screen, how would I add that to the build function after creating the game Plus 6 in another class?

Comment: You can do ir exactly the same with another game. The key is to separate the game screen and logic from the game `App` class.

Comment: okay but how do I add it to the build function since it already has self.screen = Plus5Screen. I am sure can't add "self.screen = Plus6Screen" after "self.screen = Plus5Screen"

Comment: The `self.screen = Plus5Screen` is in the `plu5.py` file, so the `self.screen = Plus6Screen` would be in the `plus6.py` file.